# Using anonymous function with stream's map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects that I want to modify with one of the setters is it bad to call it in anonymous map and what are the possible side effects:

```
.stream().map(foo -> { foo.setDate(date);return foo;})
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Intellij is telling me to switch it to peek

```
.stream().peek(foo -> foo.setDate(date).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But I read that peek should be used for debugging only. Should I avoid both ways?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `foreach` ?

```
.forEach(foo -> { foo.setDate(date);})
```

You don't even need to `stream` the collection.

You will save yourself the cost of creating a new collection as well.

Comment: I am doing list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(foo.getItems()
                .stream().map(item -> { item.setDate(date);return item;})
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));

Comment: list requires observablelist and I am using the collections.toList()

Comment: foo.getItems().forEach(item -> { item.setDate(date);}) then list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(foo.getItems() ))

Comment: You can simplify further to `.forEach(foo -> foo.setDate(date))`

Answer (score 1):

The first way is more than OK in this case, what matters is that you don't change the source of the stream structurally, meaning adding/removing elements to it *while* you stream.

And indeed IntelliJ is wrong about this, a `map` is a lot more suited than a `peek` (it is only for debugging).

Comment: Actually, both are equally wrong. Both are not intended for this and both will exhibit the same problems in practice.

Comment: @Holger interesting how `map` would be wrong? May be for this simple example yes, but otherwise cant tell how

Comment: You already know the answer. Whether the `map` function is actually evaluated, depends on the terminal operation, hence, it’s not appropriate for applying side effects to all elements. Further, if the same object appears multiple times in the source, there is interference, even if the side effect is limited to the current element. Just everything that applies to the side effects within `peek`, applies to side effects within `map` as well.